# Can't Edit/Add Product at the Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, marketplace

I am not able to edit Products on my Magento Backend and when I click Add Product, the proper format ie- General,Prices,Design etc doesn't appear.

I have got this issue after I installed Manthan Multi-Seller Marketplace and since then I cannot make any changes to my Products.

[image: Edit Product Error-Screenshot]

[image: Add Product Screenshot]

Comment: have you tried disabling the  Manthan Multi-Seller Marketplace module and see if you can edit the Products?

Comment: Yes, I tried uninstalling the Manthan Multi-Seller Marketplace module but, still the issue persists,it says Source model "marketplace/catalog_product_attribute_status" not found for attribute "product_status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by mistake, the module has been installed incorrectly. One or several tables hasn't been installed. Try to reinstall this module by deleting information about it from the `core_resource` table and clearing cache.

Comment: Delete which information from core_resource table.And one more thing How can I understand that the module is installed incorrectly?

Comment: Most likely, the entry in the `core_resource` table is called `manthan_marketplace_setup`. If you can't find this entry, try to look for in the modules' folder. You need to find the name of the installation folder inside the sql foler. The name ends on `_setup`.

Comment: I have done as required but now there's another error- Source model "marketplace/catalog_product_attribute_status" not found for attribute "product_status".  What should be done now?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I can say `Multi-Seller Marketplace` plugin is not installed correctly, or it's broken in between. I'll suggest you to re-install this plugin.

For this go to database, find `core_resource` table and delete `Multi-Seller Marketplace` plugin's entry. That will be something like `{modulesname}_setup`.

And just reload any page. This will re-install whole plugin again.